# CSS: Visually hide the y-axis scrollbar without affecting x-axis scrollbar

Tags: html, css, scroll, webkit, scrollbar

**Requirements**

- Visually remove the y-axis scrollbar from a `div` element
- y-axis must still be scrollable, so `overflow-y: hidden` will not work
- x-axis scrollbar must remain intact so `-webkit-scrollbar { display: none; }` will not work because it removes the x-axis scrollbar as well.

**Solution Constraints**

- Must work in recent versions of Chrome and Safari (not concerned about any other browsers)

Answer (score 0):

**Answer to my own question:**

I was actually able to accomplish this by using a combination of CSS and Javascript.

I was able to apply an `overflow-y: hidden` style to the div with the y-axis scrollbar I wanted to hide, and add a custom event listener to that div.

*Disclaimer: This solution does not provide pageUp/pageDown, or arrow keys functionality. You will need additional event listeners to get the scroll to reflect those events.*

```
const div = document.getElementById('elementId');

div.addEventListener('mousewheel', ($event) => {
  // prevent the page from scrolling when you scroll on an 
  // element with a style of overflow-y: hidden
  $event.preventDefault();

  // Calculate and set the scroll position
  div.scrollTop = div.scrollTop - $event.wheelDelta;
});
```